# updateProfile displayName, firebase authentification with react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am building an app in react native using firebase authentication. The authentication is with email and password that are saved well. The problem I have is that I also want to save a username that is stored in the displayName property, the updateProfile function is not reading me.

```
This is my code, inside the return I have the inputs that take the userName, email and password



import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { themeColors } from '../theme'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { ArrowLeftIcon } from 'react-native-heroicons/solid';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { updateProfile } from 'firebase/auth';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../firebaseConfig';


export default function SignUpScreen() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("")



    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);


    const handleCreateAccount = () => {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                console.log("user created")
                const user = userCredential.user;
                console.log(user)
            })
            .then((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: userName
                    }).then((s) => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Account');
                    })
                }
            })

            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                Alert.alert(error.message);
            });

    }


    return (
     
    )
}
.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the updateProfile function is not reading me". Can you edit your question to clarify? Is there any error message?